# ZuulException Forwarding error,ClientException null

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, netflix-zuul

Am facing the below ZuulException exception due to SocketTimeoutException Read timed out. I am trying to put my oauth2 server behind the zuul proxy.
Please see the log trace [**here**](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1711147) , gateway's application.yml entries [**here**](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1711148) and application dependencies [**here**](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1711149)  . I am not using hystrix or eureka explicitly

This issue is intermittent, sometimes it is working and sometimes it isn't. Have anyone faced this before.

everything works well except API gateway.

Answer (score 1):

Try to define the below properties. It seems that you're using Zuul with Eureka. In this case, `RibbonRoutingFilter` will be used instead of `SimpleHostRoutingFilter`. If so, you need to define readTimeout and connectTimeout for ribbon instead of `zuul.host` properties.

```
ribbon:
  ReadTimeout: 10000
  ConnectTimeout: 10000

oauth2:
  ribbon:
    ReadTimeout: 10000
    ConnectTimeout: 10000
```